# OpenCV 3 ORB GPU detectAndComputeAsync Assertion failed error

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I'm using the Cuda::ORB in OpenCV3 for feature detection.
When I use the Synchronous version of the function `detectAndCompute`
like this

`orb_gpu->detectAndCompute(input, mask_gpu,keypoints, output);`

it doesn't raise any error and the code works fine, but when I use the Asynchronous version

`orb_gpu->detectAndComputeAsync(input, mask_gpu,keypoints, output);`

it raises this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (d == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1]
>   == 1 || sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0)) in create, file /home/yahya/Sources/OpenCV3.1/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line
>   2369
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what(): 
>   /home/yahya/Sources/OpenCV3.1/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2369:
>   error: (-215) d == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1] == 1 ||
>   sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0) in function create

Does anybody have a solution for this error?

Comment: Could you give us a little more code? Such as what is `orb_gpu`, `input`, etc.?